# getting stuck when started on editor with no any logs (perhaps because of time string parsing)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 3D game on unity, and want to add the energy increasing functionality.

I tried the below code which made my game stuck when trying to test on editor

```
 void Start()
{

    // to calculate time since player left app to be used for energy increment
    currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    lastTime = PlayerPrefs.GetString("lastTime", currentTime);
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
    {

    timeDT = Convert.ToDateTime(currentTime , null);
    CurrentTimeDT = Convert.ToDateTime(lastTime, null);
    timeSpan = timeDT.Subtract(CurrentTimeDT);
    timeDifference = int.Parse(timeSpan.TotalSeconds.ToString());

    } else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor)
    {
        lastTime = lastTime.Substring(10);
        currentTime = currentTime.Substring(10);
    timeDT = DateTime.ParseExact(currentTime, "h:mm:ss tt" , null);
    CurrentTimeDT = DateTime.ParseExact(lastTime,"h:mm:ss tt", null);
    timeSpan = timeDT.Subtract(CurrentTimeDT);
    timeDifference = int.Parse(timeSpan.TotalSeconds.ToString());
    }
    energy = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("energy", 5); //get last saved energy
    energy += Mathf.Abs(timeDifference / 300); //add one energy every 5 minutes since the player left app
    if (energy > 5) // the maximum energy amount
    {
        energy = 5;
    }
```

I expected it to increase energy by 1 for each 5 minutes since the player left the game. But I got the unity program stuck with no any outputs. I tried building the game for android I got some logging from logcat.

```
08-21 04:15:52.153 1747-1760/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity bnds=[8,618][149,848]} from uid 1000 on display 0
08-21 04:15:52.153 1747-1760/? V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{2efb58cd token=Token{24ade64 ActivityRecord{c6b2ff7 u0 com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t39}}} to stack=1 task=39 at 0
08-21 04:15:52.157 2042-2042/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1341 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:382 com.vphone.launcher.Stats.recordLaunch:129 com.vphone.launcher.Launcher.c:3766 com.vphone.launcher.Launcher.onClickAppShortcut:3718 
08-21 04:15:52.161 1747-1770/? V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{28d195fc u0 Starting com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall} at 3 of 6 (after Window{759b336 u0 com.vphone.launcher/com.vphone.launcher.Launcher})
08-21 04:15:52.201 2042-2252/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.bindService:1770 android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:539 com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zza.zza:-1 com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zza.zza:-1 com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzc:-1 

    --------- beginning of main
08-21 04:15:52.202 2042-2042/? D/yeshen: launcher onpause
08-21 04:15:52.231 1747-2657/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 10837:com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall/u0a47 for activity com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
08-21 04:15:52.242 10837-10837/? D/houdini: [10837] Initialize library(version: 5.0.7b_x.48396 RELEASE)... successfully.
08-21 04:15:52.543 10837-10837/? D/houdini: [10837] Added shared library /data/app/com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall-1/lib/arm/libmain.so for ClassLoader by Native Bridge.
08-21 04:15:52.619 1747-2032/? V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{5e10f3d u0 com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} at 3 of 7 (before Window{28d195fc u0 Starting com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall})
08-21 04:15:52.654 1747-1760/? V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{3ef00883 u0 SurfaceView} at 3 of 8 (before Window{5e10f3d u0 com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity})
08-21 04:15:52.728 1747-1770/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +526ms
08-21 04:15:52.728 1747-2034/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1327 com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.hideCurrentInputLocked:1992 com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.windowGainedFocus:2082 com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub.onTransact:221 com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onTransact:873 
08-21 04:15:52.738 2042-2042/? D/yeshen: launcher onstop
08-21 04:15:52.738 2042-2042/? D/Tinker.DefaultAppLike: onTrimMemory level:20
08-21 04:15:52.741 2042-2277/? W/DebugConnManager: getNetworkInfo() on networkType 1
08-21 04:15:52.823 10837-10855/? I/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 2, Memory = 2022mb
08-21 04:15:52.823 10837-10855/? I/Unity: SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 2 big (mask: 0x3), 0 little (mask: 0x0)
08-21 04:15:52.825 10837-10855/? I/Unity: ApplicationInfo com.Serv4Me.SlidingBall version 1.0 build 52251d08-2db4-4bc0-b627-11ed2dc44951
08-21 04:15:52.825 10837-10855/? I/Unity: Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.1f1 (ca4d5af0be6f)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Disabled'
08-21 04:15:53.267 10837-10855/? E/EGL_emulation: [eglGetConfigAttrib] Bad attribute idx 12513
08-21 04:15:53.267 10837-10855/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 10855: eglGetConfigAttrib(761): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
08-21 04:15:53.267 10837-10855/? E/EGL_emulation: [eglGetConfigAttrib] Bad attribute idx 12514
08-21 04:15:53.267 10837-10855/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 10855: eglGetConfigAttrib(761): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
08-21 04:15:53.267 10837-10855/? E/EGL_emulation: [eglGetConfigAttrib] Bad attribute idx 1
08-21 04:15:53.267 10837-10855/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 10855: eglGetConfigAttrib(761): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
08-21 04:15:53.307 10837-10855/? D/Unity:  GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_EXT_robustness GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float ANDROID_gles_max_version_3_1 GL_OES_vertex_array_object
08-21 04:15:54.693 7816-7869/? E/PlayCommon: [290] afxf.d(308): Failed to connect to server for server timestamp: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
08-21 04:15:54.753 2690-2690/? W/ChimeraUtils: Non Chimera context
08-21 04:15:54.845 7816-7869/? I/PlayCommon: [290] afxf.d(124): Connecting to server: https://play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
08-21 04:15:54.847 7816-7869/? E/PlayCommon: [290] afxf.d(287): Failed to connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
08-21 04:15:58.283 1747-1817/? D/ConnectivityService: releasing NetworkRequest NetworkRequest [ id=58, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
08-21 04:15:58.290 2042-2344/? D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524296
08-21 04:15:58.902 1747-2032/? W/SensorService: sensor 00000000 already enabled in connection 0xa15fb460 (ignoring)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the PlayerPrefs from both the editor and android device which has the wrong datetime string parse. hope this helps someone else.